# Pass Ethernet Interface Alias as value to create a secondary IP on that Interface

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a couple of VM's in Azure that I need to temporary add secondary IP in the Windows Server (guest os).
I don't know the Interface Aliases of NIC's present in that systems (systems will be newly generated by ASR), I know the primary IP's assigned.

I need to add secondary IP to only one existing NIC in the OS, I plan to use command:
`New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -InterfaceAlias "NAME" -SkipAsSource $true`

How can I grab name of Interface Alias from this NIC and put on command above, or maybe there is some other solution to do that?

Thanks from advance for every help.

Current code:

```
$PrimaryIP = "10.20.30.5"
$NetworkInterface = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress -eq $PrimaryIP }

$InterfaceAlias = $NetworkInterface.InterfaceAlias

$SecondaryIP = "10.20.30.6"  
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $SecondaryIP -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -PrefixLength 24 -SkipAsSource $false

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -NextHop 10.20.30.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I grab name of Interface Alias from this NIC using primary IP's?

To retrieve the interface alias (interface name) based on the `Primary IP address` of the `NIC`.

**Here is the PowerShell command.**

```
#Replace with your primary IP address
$PrimaryIP = "192.168.1.5"
$NetworkInterface = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress -eq $PrimaryIP }
```

**Output:**

[image]

To add the secondary `IP` to `NIC`.

Here is the **PowerShell** command.

```
# Replace with secondary IP address
$SecondaryIP = "192.168.1.15"  
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $SecondaryIP -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -SkipAsSource $true
```

**Output:**

Once the above command is run, a `secondary IP` has been assigned to the existing `NIC` that had the `primary IP` address assigned to it.

[image]

**Updated code:**

If you're encountering the issue where the primary IP is being swapped with the secondary IP after running the script, the following script will address the problem. Make sure to execute the script in the correct order.

> Note:If the script is run to add a secondary IP and the IP is assigned dynamically, it will modify the existing IP, replacing it with a new IP instead of the secondary IP. However, if the IP is assigned statically, it will successfully add the secondary IP.

```html
$PrimaryIP = "192.168.1.5"
$SecondaryIP = "192.168.1.21"

# Get interface alias for the primary IP
$NetworkInterface = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress -eq $PrimaryIP }
$InterfaceAlias = $NetworkInterface.InterfaceAlias

# Add secondary IP
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $SecondaryIP -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -SkipAsSource $true -PrefixLength 24

$AdapterIndex = (Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq $InterfaceAlias }).ifIndex

# Set the default gateway for secondary IP
$DefaultGateway = "10.20.30.1"
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $AdapterIndex -InterfaceMetric 2  
New-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $AdapterIndex -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 -NextHop $DefaultGateway
```

Comment: Hi Venkat, thank you for your reply it was really helpful but I still face some issue. First after change Default Gateway is lost but I already solved this issue so no problem on that. Bigger problem is that when I use this script first time primary IP is exchanged for one that is described as secondary in the script.  This happens regardless Primary IP is DHCP given or Static assigned in Windows. If I use the script once again but this time I use "new/secondary" IP as primary - which is now the only one IP and use the previous primary address as secondary all go ok, and I see both 2 IP's.

Comment: Hi Arhen, kindly check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but almost always when I try to assign Primary IP via GUI, default gateway is lost, so I lost connection to VM.

Finally I decided to go with this script. Maybe not look perfect but do the job:

1. Assign Secondary IP if I know only Primary IP
2. Assign SkipAsSource flag to false on primary and true to secondary
3. Assign the default gateway for NIC

`#Assign 2 IP's on NIC with Primary IP, set Primary as SaS False and Secondary SaS True`

```
$PrimaryIP = "10.20.30.10"
$NetworkInterface = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress -eq $PrimaryIP }

$InterfaceAlias = $NetworkInterface.InterfaceAlias

$SecondaryIP = "10.20.30.11"  
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $SecondaryIP -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -PrefixLength 24 -SkipAsSource $true

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -NextHop 10.20.30.1

$NetworkInterface = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress -eq $SecondaryIP }

$InterfaceAlias = $NetworkInterface.InterfaceAlias

New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $PrimaryIP -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -PrefixLength 24 -SkipAsSource $false
```